# SQL sum based on the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
pre     qty     cur
--------------------
100      -1      99
99       -10     89
89       10      99
```

Hi, I would like to update the column `pre`, `qty`, `cur`. I tried to sum `pre` and `qty` then result `cur` will bring to the next `pre` column for continue the calculation.

So far this is my query.

```
SELECT `id`, `pre` , `qty`, `cur`, `pre`+`qty` AS `cur` FROM `inventory_logs`
```

Comment: is there a column like `ID` that can use to determine the sequence or ordering of the rows ?

Comment: Yes, there have column for the `ID`

Comment: In sqlserevr 'Delimited identifiers Are enclosed in double quotation marks (") or brackets ([ ]).' - Yours are delimited by backticks which are mysql delimiters are you sure this is a sqlserver question?

Comment: Please show the results you want.  I'm confused; you have three columns and you say you want to update *all* of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your desired output at the top of your question, you can use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to update your table in one shot instead of processing one `cur` at a time:

```
UPDATE inventory_logs
SET cur = pr.P
FROM inventory_logs JOIN (SELECT pre, qty, LAG(pre + qty, 0)
    OVER (Partition by pre ORDER BY id asc) AS P
    FROM inventory_logs) as pr
ON inventory_logs.pre = pr.pre;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have posted the expected results in your question.
You can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT ID,PRE,QTY,PRE+QTY AS CUR FROM inventory_logs WHERE ID=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.ID, C.CUR AS PRE, T.QTY, C.CUR + T.QTY AS CUR
  FROM CTE C
  INNER JOIN inventory_logs T 
  ON T.ID = C.ID+1
)
  SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Assuming ofcourse you want to start the calculation from `ID =1` and are ordering by ID

Answer (score -1):

Try it in sql,

```
UPDATE inventory_logs SET cur=pre + qty

SELECT id, pre , qty, cur FROM inventory_logs
```